# Hi , the springboot project i want to implement searchbar operation(returns required data by keyword)for my crudrepository by spring data JPA but,

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

> Sat Sep 29 09:33:28 IST 2018
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Required String parameter 'internship' is not present

STS Error

> 2018-09-29 09:33:28.833  WARN 2589 --- [io-8082-exec-10] 
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handlerexecution:org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'internship' is not present

UserRepository.java

```
package com.infi.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.infi.modal.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

    public List<User> findAllByInternship(String internship);
}
```

:in 
Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getUsersByinternship(@RequestParam("internship") String internship, ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<User> user = userService.findAllByInternship(internship);
    modelMap.addAttribute("users", user);
    return "welcome";
}
```

:searchbarcode
[jsp code for search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnLKO.png)

i have created internship POJO with getters and setters, constructor using fields and Tostring method and the same attributes in DB

how the search bar implementations look:
[the implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEGSG.png)

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the "name" of the input tag ,from "Internship" to "internship" (the first letter should be lowercase)
   becasuse you should make it be the same as @RequestParam("internship")

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `@RequestMapping` isn't able to find the parameter that is being sent from the previous call/page. Your issue is actually getting originated from the following code block:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getUsersByinternship(@RequestParam("internship") String internship, ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<User> user = userService.findAllByInternship(internship);
    modelMap.addAttribute("users", user);
    return "welcome";
}
```

Here the value `@RequestParam("internship")` isn't being sent properly. Also, check the form sent using network inspector in the dev mode of your browser.
As I see there are a couple of ways that you can solve this situation with:

1. Either pass the URL `/search` with all the necessary parameters (`internship` variable)

**OR**

2. You can alter the `@RequestParam` mapping to false as like the following:

   ```
   @RequestParam(value="internship", required=false) String internship
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,i tried what u said its not giving error but its not displaying the row when specified(its returning nothing).

Comment: Then you're not sending the parameter `internship` from the form before reaching this call. Check that code and add it to the question so that we can help!

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/search",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getUsersByinternship(@RequestParam(value="internship", required=false) String internship, ModelMap modelMap,HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<User> user = userService.findAllByInternship(internship);
        modelMap.addAttribute("users", user);
  request.setAttribute("mode", "ALL_USERS");
        return "welcome";
    }

Comment: Which method calls `getUsersByinternship()` method, that code you'll need to  add to the question.

Comment: my return statement sends back all users data how do i make it return table values of only specified column attributes value(when searched).

Comment: Kindly update the question with the working solution! Kindly also accept & upvote if my answer helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my solution by changing the code in Controller.java

1.By adding dependencies for the repository

2.Then,in search

@Autowired

UserRepository userRepository;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search",method=RequestMethod.POST)

 public String findAllByInternship(@RequestParam(value="internship", required=false)String internship, ModelMap modelMap,HttpServletRequest request) 
 {
List<User> user =  userRepository.findAllByInternship(internship);
 modelMap.addAttribute("users", user);
 request.setAttribute("mode", "ALL_USERS");
 return "welcome"; }
```

Thank you all who helped me to find the solution!